# is it possible to change one image on a page without changing another image using any language

Tags: html, css

I have searched google,w3schools and i have came up blank. I am working on an idle clicker game and i need one of the images to be left aligned but the main image to stay centered. Please any help would be nice

http://flameforged.altervista.org/Redsnow/Clicker/index.html

http://flaminggenius.org/

Comment: Please share fiddle or code to work on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Put this class on images you want to be aligned left/right of the screen.

```
 .left_img {
     position: absolute;
     left: 10px;
 }
 .right_img{
     position: absolute;
     right: 10px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add separate "ids" to the images, which would enable you to style them separately and style them either using inline HTML or CSS.

```
<img id = "image1" src = "someImage.jpg"> </img>
<img id = "image2" src = "anotherImage.jpg"> </img>

CSS:

#image1{
float: left
}

#image2 {
position: relative
left: 30px;
}
```

Note: for #image2 you may have to play around with the settings to get ideal middle.